# Solr zkcli.sh - Is it possible to upload config set to multiple zookeeper in a cluster at once?

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

Usually we use `zkcli.sh` provided by `Solr` itself to manage config set for solrcloud collection. And sometimes a cluster of external zookeepers (typically 3 instance in my case) is used instead of a single one.

The issue is, when upload config set to zookeeper, seems could only upload to a single zookeeper at a time.

e.g `zkcli.sh -cmd upconfig -z localhost:2181 -n dummy -d dummy/`

To upload to the other 2 (or N-1) instances, need repeating the command as many times with a different host & port.

**The questions is:**

- Does `zkcli.sh` from solr itself, provide some way to upload to the whole cluster in a single command?

**Reason I ask this:**

- After all, when setup the zookeeper cluster, each instance is aware of the rest instances in the cluster, so I think it should be possible to provide an automatic sync mechanism.
- The update within a zookeeper cluster is better to be an atomic operation, otherwise it might cause some issue, right?

Comment: Isn't the point of using Zookeeper that this is done automagically for you? Uploading to one of the nodes should automagically distribute the content across all the nodes in the zk cluster? Are you seeing any issue that breaks this assumption?

Comment: @MatsLindh I expect that to happen, but in my test, after updating a zookeeper, the other instances didn't get sync automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To upload the config to more than one zookeeper use this: `./zkcli.sh -cmd upconfig -confdir /opt/solr/collection/conf -confname config_name -z <zookeeper1 ipaddress>:2181,<zookeeper2 ipaddress>:2181,<zookeeper3 ipaddress>:2181`